# what's the "struct hack" and "type/non-type hiding"?

Tags: c++

I saw this in *cppreference*.

> Lookup for a name in a scope finds all declarations of that name, with one exception, known as the "struct hack" or "type/non-type hiding": Within the same scope, some occurrences of a name may refer to a declaration of a `class/struct/union/enum` that is not a `typedef`, while all other occurrences of the same name either all refer to the same variable, non-static data member (since C++14), or enumerator, or they all refer to possibly overloaded function or function template names

The link to the above text is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup)

I don't understand what is "struct hack" and "type/non-type hiding".

Are they the same concept? Can you give a simple explanation? It would be nice to have a snippet demonstration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the beginning, there was C. In C, declarations like these are entirely possible (and indeed frequent):

```
#include <time.h>  // defines struct tm { ... }
struct tm tm;

int stat(const char *pathname, struct stat *statbuf); // defined somewhere in POSIX headers
```

This code is totally normal in C because *tags* like `tm` or `stat` do not designate types. Only `struct tm` and `struct stat` do.

```
#include <time.h> 
tm my_time; // doesn't work in C
```

Enter C++. In C++, if you define `struct tm { ... };` then `tm` *alone* is a type name.

```
#include <time.h>
tm my_time; // OK in C++
```

But without the "one exception" detailed in your quote, C code like above would not compile with a C++ compiler.

```
#include <time.h>
struct tm tm; // would not compile without the exception 
              // because tm alone already refers to a type
              // defined in this scope
```

Since breaking perfectly good C code is not an intention of C++, the exception was invented and put in place. It basically says that you are allowed to define variables, functions, ans some other stuff with the same name as a class/struct/union tag. If you do, then the tag alone stops being a type name in this scope.

```
#include <time.h>
struct tm tm;      // compiles because of the exception
tm my_time;        // no longer compiles because `tm` variable hides the type
struct tm my_time; // OK
```

So this is the "type/non-type hiding" (because a type is hidden by a non-type)" *hack*. It's called a *hack* because it is a slight bend in an otherwise perfectly smooth and boring rule ("every name refers to one thing and one thing only"), which allows something (compatibility with old C code) that would not be possible without. Normal scope-based name hiding is not a hack. It is a perfectly regular thing, not a clever bend in anything.

Comment: I get it, this is **C++** for compatibility with **C** code. And another thing is clear also that 
 the referred declaration of **class/struct/union/enum** must not be a **typedef**. Is 
it because of **C** don't take part in with **typedef**?

Comment: @V.Wu You cannot do it with typedef in C either.

Comment: this sentence "some occurrences of a name may refer to a declaration of a class/struct/union/enum that is not a typedef", the *declaration* cannot be *typedef*. is it because of *C*  does not have *typedef*?

Comment: No, C has typedef.

Answer (score 7):

The sentence should really be understood as :

> The exception concerning name look up concerns "struct hack" also
>   named "type/non-type hiding".

So the definition of the concept you are looking for is really "type/non-type hiding".
The term "struct hack" can be confusing as it refers to the C flexible array which is a C specific implementation and not a name look up problem.

Concerning  "type/non-type hiding" it is what allows you to write something like this and compile :

```
#include <iostream>

namespace first
{
class vector
{
    public:
    int hidden;
};
}

namespace second {
  using namespace first;
  class vector
  {
      public:
      int visible;
  };
  double f()
  {
      vector f;
      f.visible=2;
      int vector = f.visible;
      return vector;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << second::f() << std::endl;
}
```

[Show on godbolt.org](https://www.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Anamespace+first%0A%7B%0Aclass+vector%0A%7B%0A++++public:%0A++++int+hidden%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Anamespace+second+%7B%0A++using+namespace+first%3B%0A++class+vector%0A++%7B%0A++++++public:%0A++++++int+visible%3B%0A++%7D%3B%0A++double+f()%0A++%7B%0A++++++vector+f%3B%0A++++++f.visible%3D2%3B%0A++++++int+vector+%3D+f.visible%3B%0A++++++return+vector%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+second::f()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

As you can see `second::vector` hides `first::vector` inside the scope of `namespace second`.

Moreover inside `f` function `int vector` hides `second::vector`.

The concept is well explained in an [IBM thread](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/name_hiding.htm) :

> If a class name or enumeration name is in scope and not hidden, it is
>   visible. A class name or enumeration name can be hidden by an explicit
>   declaration of that same name — as an object, function, or enumerator
>   — in a nested declarative region or derived class. The class name or
>   enumeration name is hidden wherever the object, function, or
>   enumerator name is visible. This process is referred to as name
>   hiding.
>
> In a member function definition, the declaration of a local name hides
>   the declaration of a member of the class with the same name. The
>   declaration of a member in a derived class hides the declaration of a
>   member of a base class of the same name.

You can also check the iso cpp standard:
[6.3.10  Name hiding[basic.scope.hiding]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) or http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.hiding

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer !. I have to say that the essential issue still exists. As above you said **the concerns "struct hack" also named "type/non-type hiding"**.  so what's the similarity between "struck hack" and "type/non-type"?

Comment: I think we are hitting a semantic issue. struct hack in c++ is meant here as a totally different concept as struct hack in C99 which should really be called flexible arrays (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Also note that C++ does not have flexible array members. I really think that you could suggest to the website cpprefrence to delete the "struct hack" part. Moreover struct hack as a c++ feature is never mentionned in the iso cpp standard (see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf). I have edited my answer to quote this paper.

Comment: Scopes and namespaces have nothing to do with the subject of the question. The type/non-type hiding refers to this sequence: `struct vector {}; int vector = 42;` where both definitions are **in the same scope**.