# What does "class classname* funcname(void) "mean in C++?

Tags: c++

I found the following code in a header file and the "BOOT" class is defined in another header file.

```
class BOOT* boot(void);
```

It looks like a declaration of a function, *but* it begins with `class`.

Comment: It's a feature inherited from C. In C you must add the `struct`/`union` keyword whenever you refer to one. In C++, this is optional. Thus, `class BOOL` = `BOOL`

Comment: In C++ is solely basically allows you to _declare_ a function type which returns a pointer of an (possibly incomplete) class type, but without having to forward declare the class type `BOOT` prior to the declaration. An alternative would be `class BOOT; // forward declaration` followed by `BOOT* boot();`.,

Comment: @king_nak They are not strictly the same, `class BOOL` also works as a forward declaration here.

Comment: Compare with old-fashioned `typedef struct` constructs and give your brain a whirl ;)

Comment: @king_nak Another benefit of saying "class BOOL" is that -- as the cppreference quote cited by Rene points out --  it's valid even if somebody previously declared an (unrelated) typedef BOOT.

Comment: This has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007165/class-keyword-in-variable-definition-in-c

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is an elaborated type specifier:

> Elaborated type specifiers may be used to refer to a previously-declared class name (class, struct, or union) or to a previously-declared enum name even if the name was hidden by a non-type declaration. They may also be used to declare new class names.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier

Taking from answers of Artefacto and dfrib because it brings it on point: It is equivalent to:

```
class BOOT;
BOOT* boot(void);
```

In your example it essentially does a forward declaration of the class BOOT if it is not known yet. See this example `struct Data* Data;` from the same page:

```
struct Node {
    struct Node* Next; // OK: lookup of Node finds the injected-class-name
    struct Data* Data; // OK: declares type Data at global scope
                       // and also declares the data member Data
    friend class ::List; // error: cannot introduce a qualified name
    enum Kind* kind; // error: cannot introduce an enum
};
 
Data* p; // OK: struct Data has been declared
```

Comment: Compare and contrast with: `class BOOT; using BOOT = int; BOOT* boot(void);`

Comment: Is this useful beyond saving a line? I would be confused by this syntax, too, and would prefer the two declarations separately for readability.

Comment: @ahota: The documentation says "Elaborated type specifiers may be used to refer to a previously-declared class name (class, struct, or union) or to a previously-declared enum name even if the name was hidden by a non-type declaration." (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57865891 for details)
It has it's place. I personally prefer being more explicit, i.e. I would avoid the syntax, if it is not needed. However, this is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 20):

It is the same as this:

```
class BOOT;
BOOT* boot(void);
```

So it's a pointer to `class BOOT`, but with a declaration of the class as well. The class need not be defined at this point.

Answer (score 12):

> What does “class classname* funcname(void) ”mean in C++?

It is a function declaration.

> It looks like a declaration of a function, *but* it begins with "class".

`class classname*` is the return type of the function. `class classname` is an elaborated type specifier.

Answer (score 8):

#### Different forms of forward declarations used to introduce *class-name*:s into its scope

In C++ you may *declare* a function type whose return type contains a class type that is defined elsewhere, as long as you either explicitly *forward declare* the class type prior to the function declaration:

```
class BOOT;
BOOT* boot();
```

but you may likewise place the forward declaration in-line in the function declaration:

```
class BOOT* boot();
```

This is one of the places where, possibly somewhat unexpectedly, forward declarations can be used. Another example is as in the template argument list for a type-template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
struct Identity { using type = T; };

using IdentityBoot = Identity<struct BOOT>;
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ also a forward declaration

// OK
BOOT* boot();

// OK
typename IdentityBoot::type* another_boot();
```

---

#### Elaborated type specifiers can be used to introduce *names* into its scope

Formally, it's an *elaborated-type-specifier*, governed by [[dcl.type.elab]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.elab),

> ```
> elaborated-type-specifier:
>     class-key [...]
>     [...]
> ```

that is used to, as per [[class]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#1), make a *class-name* that is introduced into the scope where the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used [**emphasis** mine]:

> A class is a type. **Its name becomes a *class-name*** ([class.name]) **within its scope.** [...]
>
> Class-specifiers **and *elaborated-type-specifiers* are used to make class-names**.